# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," / typescript 'as' keyword not recognized

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to blur the input element when enter is pressed, but since e.target does not contain blur() method I want ts to consider it as a HTMLInputElement (or pretty much anything that would compile). But I get a compilation error:

```
src/components/EditableLabel.tsx
  Line 50:31:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  48 |             onKeyDown={e => {
  49 |                 if (e.key === 'Enter') {
> 50 |                     (e.target as HTMLInputElement).blur();
     |                               ^
  51 |                     clearSelection();
  52 |                 }
  53 |             }}
```

How can I make it work?

edit: Here's the whole component as requested, also modified a bit for other purposes

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

interface ELProperties {
    editMode: boolean;
    setEditMode: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
    focus?: boolean;
    exitOnBlur?: boolean;
    maxDigits?: number;
    other?: any;
}

// Returns an input which allows to be editable when in edit mode
export function EditableLabel({
    editMode,
    setEditMode,
    setValue,
    focus = false,
    exitOnBlur = false,
    maxDigits,
    ...other
}: ELProperties): JSX.Element {
    const element = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    // clear all text selection
    const clearSelection = () => {
        window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
    };

    // focus on input if in edit mode, otherwise clear selection
    useEffect(() => {
        if (focus && element.current) {
            element.current.focus();
            element.current.select();
        } else clearSelection();
    }, [editMode]);

    return (
        <input
            ref={element}
            type='text'
            spellCheck='false'
            disabled={!editMode}
            onChange={e => {
                const value = e.target.value;
                if (!maxDigits || value.length <= maxDigits) setValue(value);
            }}
            onKeyDown={e => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    (e.target as HTMLInputElement).blur();
                    clearSelection();
                }
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
                if (exitOnBlur) setEditMode(false);
            }}
            {...other}
        />
    );
}
```

edit: I've got the same error using 'as' keyword in the other parts of code too so it's probably not related to the component, here's the config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

edit: Ts throws every time I use 'as' keyword anywhere in my code, example below. The project uses CRA and webpack, . tsconfig was automatically generated.

```
let t: any = 123;
console.log(t as number);
// Produces the same error
```

Comment: Can you show the whole component usage?

Comment: I would recommend that you take the code inside the brackets and assign it to a variable, and call that function from there instead

Comment: Tried it and got the same result

Comment: I created a stackblitz but I couldn't replicate your issue :/ https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kl2cxr?file=Hello.tsx It sounds like some problem with your linter/typescript configuration. Can you share your .tsconfig and .eslint?

Comment: This might be it because the error showed in other parts of the project too. I put the .tsconfig to the post, not using .eslint tho

Comment: Yes, it might be. If you could create a [MCVE], that would make it easier for us to help you. Do you have a `.tslint`?

Comment: I've updated the post with example and more info

Comment: I don't have a .tslint

Comment: How about a `eslintConfig` object or something similar inside your `package.json`? Your error message really seems to come from eslint from what I can see on the internet, that's why I suspect it has to do with that.

Comment: Ok, I might have figured it out somehow. Turns out, after ejecting the code actually started working correctly and the issue is gone. Still don't know why would that happen and this doesn't feel like a correct way to fix this, so I'm not really treating it as a sollution.

Comment: Problem solved, I've copied the `eslintCache` key from after the eject (`"eslintConfig": {"extends": "react-app"}`) to the not ejected project and it's working again. Thanks a lot for the help, you can post it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outermost brackets on what you are assigning to `onKeyDown`, i.e.

```js
  56 |             onKeyDown = e => {
  57 |                 if (e.key === 'Enter') {
  58 |                     (e.target as HTMLInputElement).blur();
  59 |                     setEditMode(false);
  60 |                 }
  61 |             }
```

Comment: OP's code is probably a react component prop in jsx/tsx, so it should actually be brackets around

Comment: Ah, good point @ShamPooSham